# How can I pass a fixed value to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

My function needs a reference as input:

```
test = foo(&xyz)
```

Is it possible to pass a fixed value? Of course

```
test = foo(1.23)
```

does not work. I could define a new variable to pass but is this really necessary?

Thanks

Philipp

Comment: Yes it's necessary to use a variable. Please take some time to read about the different [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category) and learn about the differences between *lvalues* and *rvalues*.

Comment: The function you showed takes a pointer, not a reference. C doesn't pass anything by reference, only by value. We pass a pointer to *simulate* that. And a pointer has to point at an object. A constant is not an object in C.

Comment: You need to use a variable, you need to pass a pointer to a memorylocation.

Comment: We usually pass a pointer either for efficiency or, in the case shown in passing a `double`, because the function overwrites the value.  If it was allowed to pass a literal (like 1.23) then the function would attempt to overwrite a constant and would probably crash the program.

Comment: `foo(&(double){1.23})` instead of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't take the address of a constant, such as `1.23` in C. But, you can use a compound literal to create an unnamed object, and take its address [as suggested by @BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430900/how-can-i-pass-a-fixed-value-to-a-pointer#comment77823632_45430900):

```
test = foo(&(double){ 1.23 });
```

It is unclear why you might want to do this, though, since usually when a pointer is passed into a function, the idea is that the object will be modified and used again after modification. Without an identifier, there would be no way to access the object created by the compound literal after `foo()` has returned.

Comment: I wanted do this because in the case xyz exceeds an upper bound xyz_max, I want to pass xyz_max. foo does not return a constant value foo_max, because foo actually needs more variables than only xyz and those are still variables (and not constants). So, I wanted to calculate test = foo(1.23, &a, &b) in that special case.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to pass a fixed value?

Not exactly, but see below.

> I could define a new variable to pass but is this really necessary?

This is usually the best way to do this.

```
double x = 1.23;
test = foo(&x);
```

---

Let's consider what would happen if the language allowed an expression like this:

```
test = foo(&1.23);
```

This immediately creates questions: What memory location would the pointer refer to?  What would be the lifespan of that memory location?  What should happen if the function `foo()` assigns a value to that location?

Requiring a variable to point to makes the answers to these questions explicit.  The pointer refers to the memory location where the variable's value is stored.  The guaranteed lifespan of that memory location corresponds to the scope of the variable.  If `foo()` assigns a value to the pointer, the value of the variable should change.

---

**Edit:** As BLUEPIXY pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430900#comment77823632_45430900), C99 does provide a kind of syntactic sugar for this called a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), which acts as an lvalue.

```
test = foo(&(double){1.23});
```

This is semantically equivalent to the following:

```
double tmp = 1.23;
test = foo(&tmp);
```